# React Autocomplete component; how to not pass the event in the onChange method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I have added an Autocomplete component to my React page. It looks like this:

```
class Koppel extends Component<PropsType, State> {
  constructor(props: PropsType) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      geviUnCombis: new Array<GeviUnCombi>()
    };
  }

  public render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.autoSuggest}>
        <Autocomplete
          ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: 200, overflow: 'auto' } }}
          disablePortal
          autoHighlight={true}
          options={this.props.geviUnCombis}
          onChange={(event, value) => this.onSelect(event, value)}
          getOptionLabel={(geviUnCombi) => (geviUnCombi.geviCode ? geviUnCombi.geviCode : "") + "/" + geviUnCombi.unCode}
          renderInput={(input) => <TextField {...input} label="Type"/>}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  private onSelect(event, value) {
    this.props.functies.create(value);
  }
}
```

This code does what it's supposed to, except for 1 small problem. OnChange passes both a `SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>` and a `GeviUnCombi` (the option, what I need).

However, I can't figure out how to only pass the value, not the event. I feel like it should be easy, and have searched on how to do it both in the React documentation and on SO, but all example code implements the Autocomplete totally different from what I have. I feel like there's a specific word / term for the issue which I sadly don't know.

I tried doing `onChange={(value) => this.onSelect(value)}`, but this resulted in only the `SyntheticEvent` being given. If someone could help me I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: The event will always be the first argument, and the value will always be the second. You don't have to use the event if you don't care about it, but it always exists. `onChange={(event, value) => this.onSelect(value))}`

Comment: Then I get an error: 'event' is declared but its value is never read.
I just now saw that VS Code suggested a quick fix, which was to add an underscore to event. That seems to suppress the error. I'll look into it a bit more just to be sure

Comment: That's a lint error, designed to point out possible mistakes in your code. While it's useful in general, i personally configure mine to allow leading arguments in functions, specifically for cases like this. Assuming you're using [eslint's no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#args) rule, see the `args` option for how to set this up. Or you could do the underscore, which is a convention to say "yeah, there's an argument here, but i don't plan to use it"

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Nicholas Tower in the comments, using an underscore solved the problem. Working code:

```
onChange={(_event, value) => this.onSelect(value)}
```